# how to share button add on react.js page

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpxGQ.png)

How to put a share button on the react.js page.Clicking on the share button will come on Facebook Gmail Another social site icone.

Answer (score -2):

#### Use `reactjs-popup` npm library.

Example :-

```js
import React from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

const PopupExample = () => (
  <Popup trigger={<button>Share</button>} position="right center">
    <div>Popup content here !!</div>
    <button>Facebook</button>
    <button>Gmail</button>
  </Popup>
);
```

##### Demo:- https://react-popup.elazizi.com/#demo